# change menu color on mouseover

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm building a website through WP, and i've gotta change mouseover color to blue.
I can't figure out how to do that.

[This is the website](http://equa.it/bergamini)

I've tried selecting it through id

```
#menu-menu-principale-effettivo a:hover{
    color:blue;
}
```

But it didn't work.
I've tried to look on the net but since i'm new to css, i've probably miss understood how to do that.

Thank's in advance

[Solved] by adding at the end of the static.css file:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) 
{
#cshero-header-navigation .main-navigation .menu-main-menu > li:hover > a {
color: #073576 !important;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
#cshero-header-navigation .main-navigation .menu-main-menu > ul > li > a .menu-title:before, #cshero-header-navigation .main-navigation .menu-main-menu > li > a .menu-title:before {
background-color: #073576 !important;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) 
{
#cshero-header-navigation .main-navigation .menu-main-menu > li.current-menu-ancestor > a {
color: #073576 !important;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px)
{
    #cshero-header-navigation .main-navigation .menu-main-menu > li.current-menu-item > a
    {
        color: #073576 !important;
    }
}
```

note: wp is a weird thing, the custom css I was trying to put in wasn't working through the "custom css" tool and I had to write it manually into the file.

Comment: Which part of your content needs to be blue on hover??

Comment: watch @stivo s answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `!important` tag after your css property. For example `#menu-item:hover{
color: blue !important;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Add this css

```
ul#menu-menu-principale-effettivo a span:hover{
color:blue
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the styles to your links.

```
 <a href="http://www.equa.it/bergamini/home"
 class="menufinale"
 onMouseOver="this.style.color='#00F'"
 onMouseOut="this.style.color='#999999'">
<span class="menu-title">Home</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#menu-menu-principale-effettivo a:hover{
color:blue !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `css`

```
#menu-menu-principale-effettivo li a span.menu-title:hover{
    color:blue;
}
```